# Can't pass string value

Tags: java, android

I want to create a simple calulator, and I get value of second activity of 0 no matter what I write in text View.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayResultActivit.class );
    EditText edittext = findViewById(R.id.liczba);
    EditText edittext2 = findViewById(R.id.liczba2);
    int wpis2 = Integer.valueOf(edittext.getText().toString());
    int wpis = Integer.valueOf(edittext2.getText().toString());
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putInt("wpis", wpis);
    extras.putInt("wpis2", wpis2);
    startActivity(intent);
```

2 activity :

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    int wpis = 0;
    if (extras != null) {
        wpis = extras.getInt("wpis1");
    }
    int wpis2 = 0;
    if (extras != null) {
        wpis2 = extras.getInt("wpis2");
    }


    TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.result);
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(wpis) + String.valueOf(wpis2));
```

Comment: Just an observation: You store as `"wpis"` but retrieve as `"wpis1"`.

Comment: And the value of edittext goes into wpis2, and edittext2 goes into wpis ....

Comment: Isn't it also logic that you link the extras variable to the intent? Something like intent.setExtra(extras)

Comment: Also, if you're trying to do a sum (in last line of "2 activity") it's really just doing a string concat of the two numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mention in the comment. You also need to link the Bundle variable with the Intent variable. See the follow link: https://zocada.com/using-intents-extras-pass-data-activities-android-beginners-guide/

```
//create a Bundle object
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
//Adding key value pairs to this bundle
//there are quite a lot data types you can store in a bundle
extras.putString("USER_NAME","jhon Doe");
extras.putInt("USER_ID", 21);
extras.putIntArray("USER_SELCTIONS", [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
...
//create and initialize an intent
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
//attach the bundle to the Intent object
intent.putExtras(extras);
//finally start the activity
startActivity(intent);
```

So your code needs to be:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayResultActivit.class );
EditText edittext = findViewById(R.id.liczba);
EditText edittext2 = findViewById(R.id.liczba2);
int wpis2 = Integer.valueOf(edittext.getText().toString());
int wpis = Integer.valueOf(edittext2.getText().toString());
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putInt("wpis", wpis);
extras.putInt("wpis2", wpis2);

intent.putExtras(extras);

startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks ! Stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code to:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayResultActivit.class );
EditText edittext = findViewById(R.id.liczba);
EditText edittext2 = findViewById(R.id.liczba2);
int wpis2 = Integer.valueOf(edittext.getText().toString());
int wpis = Integer.valueOf(edittext2.getText().toString());
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putInt("wpis", wpis);
extras.putInt("wpis2", wpis2);
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
```

You forgot about putExtras() method!

Comment: Thanks ! Stupid mistake.